# How to install Ubuntu Server in an XFS file system?

Tags: boot, server, grub2, partitioning

I'm unable to install Ubuntu Server 18.04 (fresh install, I use live version from USB install) to XFS partition. I selected manual partition, manually selected XFS as the filesystem type for `/` directory. The installer automatically create `/boot/efi` partition and I think it's fine. Also, there's no problem during installation. After installation however, the GRUB error happened.

How to do this correctly? Is there any tutorial for fresh install of Ubuntu Server to XFS?

[image: GRUB error]

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-server#0

Comment: note: I don't think XFS has anything to do with your grub issue (*where I'd check your machine's bios settings first for that*), but your question was about tutorial for install with xfs (which is a default *fs* for certain conditions anyway)

Comment: well.. after some search on Google. XFS is impossible to install on live cd image. So I abandoning the XFS. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1060323

Answer (score 0):

Installing Ubuntu on XFS is possible,

### but:

1. `/boot/efi` should be FAT (any of FAT8, FAT16, FAT32)¹
2. `/` should be `EXT4`²
3. individual specific directories can be mounted on `XFS` where needed.³

**However:** putting *everything* on `XFS` doesn't make sense at the time of this writing. (Who knows what the future and `grub3` will bring...)

<sub>**Note 1:** [Source](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_8_final.pdf), Section 5
13.3</sub>
<sub>**Note 2:** [Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace), Section 1.1</sub> 
<sub>**Note 3:** [Source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZFS), Section "Use Cases"</sub>

Comment: This needs some references.

Comment: @fkraiem See [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1161476/revisions)

Comment: Section 13.3 in Note 1

Comment: @mook765 Thanks!  Updated!!:  **:-)**

Comment: I don't understand this answer. So, you recommend to install Ubuntu on XFS but, you pointed out some posts that don't recommend. So, what is the good answer here.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XFS#Disadvantages:~:text=GRUB%2DSupport%20is%20in%20an%20early%20stage%2C%20therefore%20using%20xfs%20as%20boot%2Dfilesystem%20can%20be%20a%20bad%20idea might be a good citation for the "However" point. With mounting specific directories, probably no citation is needed, and the provided one is for ZFS anyway.